# Python Beautiful Soup img tag inside a div parsing wrong link showing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

theurl= 'http://es.ninemanga.com/chapter/Dragon%20Ball%20Multiverse/279006.html'

req = Request(theurl  + '.html', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
thepage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")


for divs in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "pic_box"}):

    temp = divs.find('img', {"id" : "manga_pic_1"})
    temp1 = temp.get('src')
    print(temp1 + "\n")
```

I want to get all `div` tags with a `class pic_box` and inside of them all the `img` tags and their `src`

I have done this correctly with `soup.findAll('div', {"class": "pic_box"})`
and then `temp.get('src')` but somehow I get:

```
http://a8.ninemanga.com/es_manga/43/555/279006/4c58c372ca4561627e5a01f6c841290e.jpg
```

instead of:

```
https://c5.ninemanga.com/es_manga/43/555/279006/939559ac8d7af80cf6b4ead0ada4f718.jpg
```

Are they somehow blocking my request or am I doing something wrong here?

[repl to test it](https://repl.it/repls/CoarseFinishedQuarks)

[referenced link in theurl variable from which I want to extract 'src'](http://es.ninemanga.com/chapter/Dragon%20Ball%20Multiverse/279006.html)

Comment: https://c5 is not within any div.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they can detect scraping requests and block them. Even using a fake agent is not working(i tried). Try out something like Selenium , that can automate browser activity and download it through your browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

the image has unique class attribute - 'manga_pic' [get image with manga_pic class](https://repl.it/repls/AgreeableUntimelyDownload)